# Writing a byte array to an address

Tags: c#, memory, byte

Deleted my old post and decided to reupload with more direct questions.

I'm trying to write bytes to a memory address for my C# menu, writing singular a singular byte or int isn't an issue. I have an issue trying to write multiple bytes.

The code below is writing a singular byte to increase the player speed to 555, which works perfectly fine.

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int nSize, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

    byte[] memory = { 555 };
    WriteProcessMemory(Game.hProc, Player.PlayerSpeedOffSet, memory, memory.Length, out _);
```

The part I'm having issues with is when I try and write multiple bytes to an address.

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int nSize, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

    byte[] memory = { 90, 90, 90 };
    WriteProcessMemory(Game.hProc, Player.UnlimitedAmmoOffSet, memory, memory.Length, out _);
```

"90 90 90" being unlimted ammo and to disable it, i'd write to the same address with "89 50 04".

This worked just fine with **memory.dll** so the handle and offset is just fine, it's just something to do with **my writing to memory**.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong, the logic itself is correct.

Comment: Did you check the return value, number of bytes written (in your sample code you are discarding this parameter) and [Marshal.GetLastWin32Error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: After doing `MessageBox.Show(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());` right after the `WriteProcessMemory`, the output was "998", strange.

Comment: 998 = ERROR_NOACCES: Invalid access to memory location.

Comment: Ooh, So Ill have to find a way to get access to the address.

Comment: The original library I used was Memory.dll, his stuff is all open source. When using his DLL, it was all passed by string, So the address is correct from when I used his. After looking at his source, it looks like he has write protection flags that he can disable. Id have to take the same route as him. Control+F for " MemoryProtection OldMemProt = 0x00;" https://github.com/erfg12/memory.dll/blob/master/Memory/memory.cs

Comment: @Senip So you found the solution yourself and learned to check the error codes of PInvoked functions ;)

Comment: Awesome, Thank you! I technically knew how to write the bytes from the start, It just wasnt working for me and I never thought to use Marshal. Ill have to fix it when I get off of work, Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Look at the definition of the function [WriteProcessMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-writeprocessmemory):

```c
BOOL WriteProcessMemory(
  HANDLE  hProcess,
  LPVOID  lpBaseAddress,
  LPCVOID lpBuffer,
  SIZE_T  nSize,
  SIZE_T  *lpNumberOfBytesWritten
);
```

Note the type of the `nSize` parameter, it's `SIZE_T`. How wide is this type? You can look it up here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types

```c
typedef ULONG_PTR SIZE_T;
```

Okay, then what is the width of ULONG_PTR? The same documentation tells:

```c
#if defined(_WIN64)
 typedef unsigned __int64 ULONG_PTR;
#else
 typedef unsigned long ULONG_PTR;
#endif
```

So, its either 32 bits or 64 bits wide, depending on whether the process calling this function is a 32-bit or 64-bit process. (In Windows, `unsigned long` is 32-bit wide.)

Now look at your P/Invoke definition:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int nSize, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
```

You have defined `nSize` as a 32-bit integer. If your program is compiled to run as a 32-bit process, you got lucky and the 32-bit integer matches the 32-bit SIZE_T.

But if your program is running as a 64-bit process, your 32-bit integer does not match the 64-bit SIZE_T.

I hope using `IntPtr` instead of `int` for the *nSize* parameter should fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Unfortunately though, changing the nSize from an 'int' to an 'IntPtr' did not help. The application is using 32-bit. I just find it very strange it will change the address of anything other than an array of bytes. 

This directly changes the players points in game, But when I try to change from 89 50 04 to 90 90 90, Nothing happens. I'm quite stumped. :D

            byte[] memory = { 90, 90, 90 };
            WriteProcessMemory(Player.hproc, (IntPtr)(0x297A10), memory, (IntPtr)memory.Length, out _);